# Ehcache: unexpected behavior when evicting cache elements

Tags: java, ehcache, spring-cache

I have two cached methods:

```
@Cacheable(value = CacheName.CACHE_STATIC, key="'getImageUserLayer'.concat(':').concat(#layerId)")
public byte[] getImageUserLayer(int layerId) {
```

and

```
@Cacheable(value = CacheName.CACHE_STATIC, key="'getLastModifiedUserLayer'.concat(':').concat(#layerId)")
@Override
public String getLastModifiedUserLayer(int layerId) {
```

also I have method for evicting of element:

```
@Caching(evict = {
        @CacheEvict(value = CacheName.CACHE_STATIC, key = "'getImageUserLayer'.concat(':').concat(#layerId)"),
        @CacheEvict(value = CacheName.CACHE_STATIC, key = "'getLastModifiedUserLayer'.concat(':').concat(#layerId)")
})
public void updateLayer(UserLayer layer, int layerId) {
```

Why after calling updateLayer(5510461), I get next weird behavior:

```
2020-02-10 16:47:07.065 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] TRACE o.s.c.i.CacheInterceptor - Computed cache key 'getLastModifiedUserLayer:4900061' for operation Builder[public java.lang.String com.prognoz.smkoob.data.dao.ImageServiceImpl.getLastModifiedUserLayer(int)] caches=[cacheStatic] | key=''getLastModifiedUserLayer'.concat(':').concat(#layerId)' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='' | unless='' | sync='false'
2020-02-10 16:48:32.695 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] TRACE o.s.c.i.CacheInterceptor - Invalidating cache key [getImageUserLayer:5510461] for operation Builder[public void com.prognoz.smkoob.data.dao.meta.UserLayerServiceImpl.updateLayer(com.prognoz.smkoob.domain.UserLayer.UserLayer,int)] caches=[cacheStatic] | key=''getImageUserLayer'.concat(':').concat(#layerId)' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='',false,false on method public void com.prognoz.smkoob.data.dao.meta.UserLayerServiceImpl.updateLayer(com.prognoz.smkoob.domain.UserLayer.UserLayer,int)
2020-02-10 16:48:32.701 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] TRACE o.s.c.i.CacheInterceptor - Invalidating cache key [getLastModifiedUserLayer:5510461] for operation Builder[public void com.prognoz.smkoob.data.dao.meta.UserLayerServiceImpl.updateLayer(com.prognoz.smkoob.domain.UserLayer.UserLayer,int)] caches=[cacheStatic] | key=''getLastModifiedUserLayer'.concat(':').concat(#layerId)' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='',false,false on method public void com.prognoz.smkoob.data.dao.meta.UserLayerServiceImpl.updateLayer(com.prognoz.smkoob.domain.UserLayer.UserLayer,int)
2020-02-10 16:48:33.591 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] TRACE o.s.c.i.CacheInterceptor - Computed cache key 'getLastModifiedUserLayer:5510461' for operation Builder[public java.lang.String com.prognoz.smkoob.data.dao.ImageServiceImpl.getLastModifiedUserLayer(int)] caches=[cacheStatic] | key=''getLastModifiedUserLayer'.concat(':').concat(#layerId)' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='' | unless='' | sync='false'
2020-02-10 16:48:33.591 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] TRACE o.s.c.i.CacheInterceptor - No cache entry for key 'getLastModifiedUserLayer:5510461' in cache(s) [cacheStatic]
2020-02-10 16:48:33.909 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] TRACE o.s.c.i.CacheInterceptor - Computed cache key 'getLastModifiedUserLayer:4900061' for operation Builder[public java.lang.String com.prognoz.smkoob.data.dao.ImageServiceImpl.getLastModifiedUserLayer(int)] caches=[cacheStatic] | key=''getLastModifiedUserLayer'.concat(':').concat(#layerId)' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='' | unless='' | sync='false'
2020-02-10 16:48:33.909 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] TRACE o.s.c.i.CacheInterceptor - No cache entry for key 'getLastModifiedUserLayer:4900061' in cache(s) [cacheStatic]
2020-02-10 16:48:33.909 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] TRACE o.s.c.i.CacheInterceptor - No cache entry for key 'getLastModifiedUserLayer:5129071' in cache(s) [cacheStatic]
2020-02-10 16:48:33.910 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] TRACE o.s.c.i.CacheInterceptor - Computed cache key 'getLastModifiedUserLayer:5129071' for operation Builder[public java.lang.String com.prognoz.smkoob.data.dao.ImageServiceImpl.getLastModifiedUserLayer(int)] caches=[cacheStatic] | key=''getLastModifiedUserLayer'.concat(':').concat(#layerId)' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='' | unless='' | sync='false'
```

Why it also invalidates another keys??? For example 4900061.

my ehcache.xml:

```
<cache name="cacheStatic"
       maxBytesLocalHeap="128M"
       maxBytesLocalDisk="2G"
       eternal="false"
       timeToLiveSeconds="7200"
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
       transactionalMode="off">
    <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
</cache>
```

Comment: Why do you think this is a weird behavior? I see only two invalidatings made in thread `http-nio-8080-exec-7`. What's about actions with 4900061 in thread `http-nio-8080-exec-3`, it seems just like a call of method `getLastModifiedUserLayer`

Comment: Indeed! All of this invokes of method are from different threads. I've improved my method using @Cacheable(sync = true) and I see now in log only single access to the cache. Thank you! Please add your answer to this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the logs, there are only two invalidatings made in thread `http-nio-8080-exec-7`:

```
2020-02-10 16:48:32.695 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] TRACE o.s.c.i.CacheInterceptor - Invalidating cache key [getImageUserLayer:5510461] for operation Builder[public void com.prognoz.smkoob.data.dao.meta.UserLayerServiceImpl.updateLayer(com.prognoz.smkoob.domain.UserLayer.UserLayer,int)] caches=[cacheStatic] | key=''getImageUserLayer'.concat(':').concat(#layerId)' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='',false,false on method public void com.prognoz.smkoob.data.dao.meta.UserLayerServiceImpl.updateLayer(com.prognoz.smkoob.domain.UserLayer.UserLayer,int)
2020-02-10 16:48:32.701 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] TRACE o.s.c.i.CacheInterceptor - Invalidating cache key [getLastModifiedUserLayer:5510461] for operation Builder[public void com.prognoz.smkoob.data.dao.meta.UserLayerServiceImpl.updateLayer(com.prognoz.smkoob.domain.UserLayer.UserLayer,int)] caches=[cacheStatic] | key=''getLastModifiedUserLayer'.concat(':').concat(#layerId)' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='',false,false on method public void com.prognoz.smkoob.data.dao.meta.UserLayerServiceImpl.updateLayer(com.prognoz.smkoob.domain.UserLayer.UserLayer,int)
```

What's about actions with `4900061` in thread `http-nio-8080-exec-3`, it seems just like a attempt to find cached value made during a call of method `getLastModifiedUserLayer`:

```
2020-02-10 16:48:33.909 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] TRACE o.s.c.i.CacheInterceptor - Computed cache key 'getLastModifiedUserLayer:4900061' for operation Builder[public java.lang.String com.prognoz.smkoob.data.dao.ImageServiceImpl.getLastModifiedUserLayer(int)] caches=[cacheStatic] | key=''getLastModifiedUserLayer'.concat(':').concat(#layerId)' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='' | unless='' | sync='false'
2020-02-10 16:48:33.909 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] TRACE o.s.c.i.CacheInterceptor - No cache entry for key 'getLastModifiedUserLayer:4900061' in cache(s) [cacheStatic]
```